# R - heatmap, setting ColSideColors

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

Can I use `palette()` to set color labels along the rows and columns of my heatmap?
I make a random 4x4 matrix, plot a heatmap and try to set the side colors:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4, 4)
c <- c(1,1,2,2)
heatmap(m,ColSideColors=c)
```

and I get the error:

```
"Error in heatmap(m, ColSideColors = c) : 
  'ColSideColors' must be a character vector of length ncol(x)"
```

Comment: You have the answer in the error message. See the result of `class(c)`. And please, avoid to use `c` as name of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

From `?heatmap`:

> ColSideColors (optional) character vector of length ncol(x) containing the color names for a horizontal side bar that may be used to annotate the columns of x.

```
set.seed(42)
m <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4, 4)
xsidecols <- c("#cdcd0d", "#0dcdcd", "#cd0dcd", "grey")
heatmap(m, ColSideColors = xsidecols)
```

[image]